# Cyclic load dependency in Clojure

Tags: clojure, cyclic-dependency

My project has a simple structure as following:

```
|- core.clj
|- dialogs.clj
|- dialogs/
   |- name_dialog.clj
```

`name_dialog` has a dependency from `core`, and `core` should require `name_dialog`.

So I have dependencies like this:

#### core.clj

```
(ns ddsl.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [clojure.xml :refer :all]
            [ddsl.dialogs :refer :all]))
```

#### dialogs.clj

```
(ns ddsl.dialogs
    (:require [ddsl.core :refer :all]))

(load "dialogs/name_dialog")
```

#### name_dialog.clj

```
(in-ns 'ddsl.dialogs)
```

When I try to run the program I'm getting the following error
`Cyclic load dependency: [ /ddsl/core ]->/ddsl/dialogs->[ /ddsl/core ]`

Please let me know, how to restructure my project (i'm a novice in Clojure).

Comment: Why does `core` require the other namespaces?

Comment: `core` produces xml from clojure "template", and has `-main` function that receives template name as argument, e.g. "name-dialog" and produces xml from it

Comment: (defn state
  [s & xs]
  (hash-map
    :tag :state
    :attrs {:name s}
    :content (if xs (vec xs) nil)))

Comment: It sounds like the functions in `core` which depend on those in other namespaces should be moved into those namespaces. `core` namespaces shouldn't need to depend on other modules.

Comment: thanks, I'll try to move them, it is quite logical. But in `core` I have function that receives name of dialog, e.g. `dialog_name`, and produces xml, so that should be loaded as a module anyway?

     (defn -main
       [dialog]
       (emit (eval (symbol dialog))))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The classic answer, not specifically Clojure related, may be to review the modules and their responsibilities.

(`->` below stands for "depends on")

Given:

```
core -> dialogs -> core
```

Extract the part of the `core` module which is required by `dialogs` into a separate shared module:

```
shared (depends on "nothing")
core -> dialogs -> shared
core -> shared (possibly)
```

As for me, cyclic dependencies are an indicator of something wrong with the design. Even when the technical problem is resolved (with load-time sequence or compilation, etc.), cyclic dependencies are typically a sign of tight coupling and still are worth fixing.